# text ellipsis priority

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have a container with display flex, that contain 2 items.
both of the items have text ellipsis to support long text.
I would like to make some priority between the items in order to make item 1 to take as match place as needed preserve some fixed space for item 2.
It means - if the container width is 200px - the min size of item 2 is 50px, I like item 1 to get up to 150px (then text ellipsis).
what is the best way of doing it?

```css
.ovf {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:300px">
  <div style="background-color: red;min-width: 50px;">
    <div class="ovf">item1 item1 item1</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;min-width: 40px;flex-shring:2">
    <div class="ovf">item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd5479eg/2/)

Comment: This is not specified enough. What should happen, when both content is short; item1 content is long and item2 content is short; item1 is short and item2 is long; both are long; both are long, but the one is significantly longer than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `flex: 1.5` or 2 to 1st section (which you want more width) and `flex:1` to another div for lesser width

```css
.ovf {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:300px">
  <div style="background-color: red;min-width: 50px;flex:1.5;">
    <div class="ovf">item1 item1 item1</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;min-width: 40px;flex:1;">
    <div class="ovf">item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

justify-content: space-between;

```css
section {
   display: flex;
   width: 50%;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
section>div {
   background: #eeeeee;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div>
      <div>Area 1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>Area 2</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way of doing it - set the second item flex attribute to 1 :

```css
.ovf {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:300px">
  <div style="background-color: red;min-width: 0">
    <div class="ovf">item1 item1 item1</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;min-width: 40px;flex:1;">
    <div class="ovf">item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 item2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks you all